# Does putting the word "off" at the end of a yaml file mean that it does not get applied?

Tags: yaml

I've found some yaml files which have the word `off` suffixed to the end of the word `yaml`  so you get a file called , for example, `role.yaml.off`

Can anybody tell me what the point of putting `off` at the end is? Does it mean that the file does not necessarily get applied?...I've been Goggling but without success

Comment: It's just a(n uncommon) conventional extension change: it has no intrinsic semantic meaning. It's like changing a `package.json` configuration file to `package.json.old` to that npm doesn't recognize it, but it still lives on as an artifact in your repository.

Comment: [Here's an example commit](https://github.com/github/covid19-dashboard/commit/5038f730e01b30c61e507593f00e7688e2c5a94e) whose message illustrates the idea: "disable update-models workflow" while changing the extension of a GitHub action workflow file from `.yaml` to `.off`.